# What are the differences between official reference versions of BLAS?

Tags: version, lapack, blas, cblas

My package manager has a number of BLAS versions (specifically CBLAS) available:

```
[IP-] [  ] virtual/cblas-1.0:0
[-P-] [ ~] virtual/cblas-3.6:0
[-P-] [ ~] virtual/cblas-3.7:0
```

If I look at their configuration, I can see they are extracted from corresponding LAPACK reference distributions.

My question is whether the differences across official releases are documented somewhere, hopefully in a changelog? Ideally also specifying the differences between the BLAS (Fortran) and CBLAS implementations? I can't find that information on the http://netlib.org/blas website.

On that website there is a link to the BLAST forum, where I can find references to 'legacy BLAS', and wonder how that fits into the versioning scheme. **edit: This appears to refer specifically to dense/banded BLAS**

Note this questions is *not* about the numerous vendor implementations that exist - I'm only interested in the netlib.org reference implementations.

Comment: btw am aware I can look at the included source/header files. But I'd rather have some documentation and understand the history.

Answer (score 0):

These are the reference implementations. Please note that individual vendors will export the routine names somewhat differently for C/C++, though.

Blas  http://www.netlib.org/blas/
Lapack http://www.netlib.org/lapack/

[This page](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/df9/group__complex16__blas__level1_ga45b00bad9285ff50cd86e97dfb04facd.html#ga45b00bad9285ff50cd86e97dfb04facd) for example documents and implements the dot product of two complex double vectors, etc. Or [this](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d7e/group__double_g_esing_gad8e0f1c83a78d3d4858eaaa88a1c5ab1.html#gad8e0f1c83a78d3d4858eaaa88a1c5ab1) the preferred divide and conquer implementation of an SVD for single real.

Change logs indicate changes between the versions: Chapter 2 on this page explains the differences between 3.7.0 and 3.8.0. For example chapter 2.5 logs improved complex Jacobi SVD.

Comment: It's clear from your answer that my question is not well worded - what I'm trying to ascertain is what the _difference between versions is_. I'm not asking what the reference version is. I will update accordingly. Thanks for your reply though.